# ambiguous name detected : Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

When I use this macro to clear `B12` when I modify `B11`, I get the compile error:

> ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change

Can you help me?

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "B11" Then
        Range("B12").ClearContents
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably, you've implemented `Worksheet_Change` twice in a module. There could be only one event handling function for one object (`Worksheet`)

Comment: I believe @John_West is right.  After that, you may also need to qualify the address `If Target.Address = "$B$11" Then`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B11")) Is Nothing Then
         Application.EnableEvents = False
          Range("B12").ClearContents
         Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: still compile error. B12 is a drop down list, perhaps I need another code?

Comment: @gdf, make sure there is no other sub or function with this name `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: maybe this link help : [Ambiguous name detected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278734.aspx).